# Removing duplicate strings from a comma separated list, in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, openrefine

I'm using Google Sheets and this is way beyond my simple scripting.

I have numerous cells containing comma separated values;

```
AA, BB, CC, BBB, CCC, CCCCC, AA, BBB, BB

BB, ZZ, ZZ, AA, BB, CC, BBB, CCC, CCCCC, AA, BBB, BB
```

I'm trying to return:

```
AA, BB, CC, BBB, CCC, CCCCC etc.

BB, ZZ, AA, CC, BBB, CCC, CCCCC etc.
```

... remove the duplicates. Per cell.

I can't get my head around a solution. I've tried every online tool that removes duplicates. BUT they all remove duplicates throughout my document.

Part of the problem is, I can't put the cells in 'alphabetical' order (which would make things simple) they have to be kept in the original order they appear.

I also have, at my disposal (but beyond my skill) Open Refine which I believe is a clever tool.

Comment: `=JOIN(",",UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,", "))))`

Comment: Wow, that is a succinct line of formula. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to do that in OpenRefine.

[image]

The formula I used is :

```
value.split(',').uniques().join(',')
```

It means : split the value in the cells by commas, remove duplicates, join them again using commas.

**EDIT :**

Another solution in OpenRefine using Python instead of GREL. This one keep better the original order.

[image]

Python/Jython Script:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dedup = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(value.replace(' ','').split(',')))
return ",".join(dedup)
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much. Also how do you make these screenshot animations?

Comment: @Callum I used a little windows app (http://www.screentogif.com/?l=fr_fr), but you can find a lot of other softwares here : https://alternativeto.net/software/screentogif/