# OpenRefine: Remove duplicate, comma separated values in cells

Tags: openrefine

How can I clean up (and later export to JSON) cells which contain comma separated, probably duplicate values?

Example of Cells:

```
+-------------+
| foo,bar,foo |
+-------------+
| bar,qux     |
+-------------+
| bar,bar     |
+-------------+
```

What I'm after is either the data split up into new columns and deduplicated like so:

```
+-----+-----+
| foo | bar |
+-----+-----+
| bar | qux |
+-----+-----+
| bar |     |
+-----+-----+
```

**or** a possibility to export the deduplicated data as a JSON array

```
+---------+
| foo,bar |
+---------+
| bar,qux |
+---------+
| bar     |
+---------+
```

to

```
"cellname": ["foo", "bar"]
"cellname": ["bar", "qux"]
"cellname": ["bar"]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first import your dataset in line-based mode so that the values are contained in a single column.

Like this.

[image]

Then, you can use this hacky Python/Jython script (already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937289/removing-duplicate-strings-from-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-cell)) to transform your column:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dedup = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(value.replace(' ','').split(',')))
return '["' + '","'.join(dedup) + '"]')
```

Result:

[image]

Finally, by clicking on "Export -> Templating", you can use a value like this in the "Row template" field:

```
  "cellnames" : {{cells["Column 1"].value}}
```

Comment: This doesn’t work with strings that contain special characters though: `Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in __temp_1559418653__
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @kbecker87 I hate Python2... Could you try with the edited version of the script?